# Insert text to TextInput() in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

Is there a way to insert text to a textinput without overwriting the previous text? Textinput().text = "something" deletes the previous text.I also want to add it everytime in a new line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has nothing to do with kivy, these are basics of python language. Instead of overwriting the varliable with `=` sign, use `+=` to append.